# Rails state machine is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I am creating a blog application in which User can post and can view his own post only.There is only one admin who can view everyone post and has feature to accept or decline users post..For example when user will share his post then admin will approve or decline that post.If he approves the post will be there if admin decline the post will be deleted .I am using state machines for that but I am having some problem .I have taken two buttons approve and decline but they are not working.
i just want that when i click on approve button so there is a column in my posts table which is given by default a value "pending" so it will change to approve or decline whichever button i click ....and if decline so the post should be deleted
when clicking approve button **undefined method `permit' for "state_event=approve":String**

[post.rb]

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'state_machine'

    has_many :documents
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user

    validates :title, presence: true, length: {in: 5..10}
    validates :body,  presence: true,length: {in: 5..200}

        #:status is the column in posts table
    state_machine :status, :initial => :pending do
        #button name which is approve
        event :approve do
           transition :pending => :approve
        end
        event :decline do
           transition :pending => :decline
        end
    end




    def self.user_post(id)
        role = User.find_role(id)
        if role == 'admin'
            Post.all

        elsif role == 'user'
            Post.where(user_id: id)

        elsif role == 'developer'
            Post.where(user_id: id)
        end             
    end

    def self.icon(extension)
        case extension
        when 'pdf'
                EXTENSION[1]['pdf']
        when 'png' || 'jpg' || 'jpeg'
            EXTENSION[0]['png']
        when 'doc' || 'odt'
            EXTENSION[2]['doc']
        end     

    end



####limit to upload files not more than ######
    def self.upload(files,post_id)  
        files.each do |file|    
        @file_extension=file.content_type.split('/')[1]         

            doc = Document.new(document: file,post_id: post_id )
            #save is a method which will save the content in the database 
            doc.save!
        end
    end
end
```

[post_controller]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 

    def index
        @posts = Post.user_post(current_user).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    end 

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def show    
        @post=find_params
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)           
        @post.user = current_user
        if @post.save
            Post.upload(params[:post][:files],@post.id)         
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = find_params

    end

    def update
        @post = find_params
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = find_params
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private
        def post_params
            p = params.require(:post)
          if current_user.roles=='admin' # or however you check if the user is authorized
            p.permit(:title, :body, :state_event)
          else
            p.permit(:title, :body)
          end


        end

        def find_params
            Post.find(params[:id])
        end

end
```

[posts/_form.html.erb]

```
<%= form_for @post,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>

     <br>
     <!-- if you want to upload multiple files at a time -->
    <%= f.label :files %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :files,:multiple => true %><br>

    <br>


    <%= f.submit %>
    <br>

<% end %>
<br>
```

[posts/edit.html.erb]

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>
<br>
        <%= form_for @post do %>
            <%= button_to 'Approve', @post, 
      params: { post: { state_event: 'approve' } } ,
      method: :patch 
        %>

        <%= button_to 'Decline', @post, 
      params: { post: {  state_event: 'decline' } } ,
      method: :patch 
        %>
        <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Please explain doesn't work.

Comment: what you are not able to understand sir?

Comment: What is not working? What did you expect to happen and what is actually happening? You need to actually do some debugging steps yourself such as checking the logs.

Comment: Clic on approve or decline, and look at the action triggered in your dev server.

Comment: first i want to now i have put my approve and decline button in my show view so will it work because i have heard when using state machine it only work with new and edit???

Comment: when i click on approve or decline it says param is missing or the value is empty: post

Comment: please see i have updated my question and i am getting the error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the state of your model [you need to set the `state_event` property](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#explicit-vs-implicit-event-transitions).

```
<%= button_to 'Approve', @post, 
      params: { post: { state_event: 'approve' } } 
      method: :patch 
%>

<%= button_to 'Decline', @post, 
      params: { post: {  state_event: 'decline' } } 
      method: :patch 
%>
```

You also need to add the parameter in the strong parameters list:

```
def post_params
  p = params.require(:post)
  if current_user.is_admin? # or however you check if the user is authorized
    p.permit(:title, :body, :state_event)
  else
    p.permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Just using `f.submit "approve"` just changes the `submit` key in the params hash.

Comment: Implementing state machines is a pretty advanced topic - you might want to figure out the basics like how passing around params in rails works first.

Comment: when i click on approve i get param is missing or the value is empty: post

Comment: what changes i have to make in update action in my controller?

Comment: I don't think you have to do any. If you do `@post.update(state_event: 'approve')` it should trigger the state change according [to the readme](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#explicit-vs-implicit-event-transitions). I haven't tested it though.

Comment: hey i am getting error i am updating my answer with the respective changes

Answer (score 0):

First of all: both your buttons approve and decline will trigger the same behaviour: they will just send your form build with form_for @posts. 
I guess when you press one of those you will send POST message to your application to the post_path(@post).
My advice for you is first of all split this buttons behaviour. Try to add value to your buttons like this:

```
 <%= f.button  :submit , name: "subaction",value: "approve"%>
```

And in your action you should be see params[:subaction] == "approve".

Comment: i just want that when i click on approve button so there is a column in my posts table which is given by default a value pending so it will change to approve or decline ....and if decline so the post should be deleted